# what is the difference between gsub using / or "?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use gsub to replace `"?"` and `"."` with empty space.

I realize that is a difference between `gsub(".", "")` and `gsub(/./, "")`, but I don't know what it is. Can Someone explain?

Also, `gsub("?","")` seems to work, and `gsub(/?/,"")` doesn't work. 
How can we make `gsub(/?/,"")` work?

Comment: Once upon a time (Ruby 1.6), there was no difference: A string pattern was automatically turned into a regular expression.  The difference started with Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally as it mentioned above `/reg/` represents regexp when `"str"` represents just a string. Your aim is to remove `?` and `.` from a string. Regexp will do the job:

```
gsub(/[?.]/, '')
```

You can read more about ruby regexp [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html). In my example `/[abc]/` will match single character `a` or `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 3):

`gsub("?", "")` matches a literal `?`, while `gsub(/?/, "")` uses [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to find a match. And in regular expressions, the `?` means that the previous character can be present either 0 or 1 times. In order to match a literal `?`, you have to escapte it:

```
gsub(/\?/, "")
```

See also the ruby documentation about [gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub)

Answer (score 1):

The former is to literally find "?" characters and replace them, while the latter is to find occurrences of 0 or 1 of a given character. `?` has a special meaning for regular expressions, which you delimit using `/`.